# Can we be able to improve an edit after we've already approved it?

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, improve-edit

I saw a question that was tagged improperly.  I went to edit it, only to discover that another user had submitted the exact same edit and it was needing approval.  I approved the edit, only to discover that it needs a second approval.  Now, I am locked from editing it at all, and this content is sitting there, wrong, with nothing I can do about it.

I understand that I should have picked the "Improve the Edit" option and then it would have gone thorugh immediately.  This doesn't help me now, though.

Could we still offer the option to "Improve the Edit", even after you have Approved it and it's waiting for the second approval?  This would make it really easy for people to fix this problem when it happens that they've made a mistake like this.

Comment: Yeah, this is not the same question as the "Reject and Improve" button.  This is about what to do after the edit has been approved by one person, and they instead wish to go back and "Improve the Edit".  Basically, just to push it through.

Comment: Maybe what you really need is the ability to remove your approval, so you can do "improve" instead?

Comment: I've just into the same problem. Approved an edit then figured I could have improved it too a bit. Now I have to wait until it gets completely approved or rejected to edit it.

Comment: In my opinion it's just plain weird that you can have enough rep to make your own edits, but not enough rep to approve someone else's edits without another user's vote. It's even weirder that you *can* approve someone else's edit, but only if you make a trivial "improvement" to it. (I feel that the current system strongly incentivises this, in order to avoid getting locked out of editing.) So while the solution suggested here would be a good one, I think an even better one would be to simply remove the requirement for the second approval if the approving user has enough rep to edit.

Comment: @Nathaniel That's for *everyone*, though, isn't it? Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the rep required to access the suggested edits review queue is the same as the rep required to make edits. What you've just proposed is equivalent to having every suggested edit reviewed by only one user.